# C - Modulo (%), how are values are being calculated for IntToString conversion where num /= 10

Tags: c, string, int, modulo

```
public static final int MAX_DIGITS = 10;

String intToStr( int num ){
    int i = 0;
    boolean isNeg = false;
    char[] temp = new char[ MAX_DIGITS + 1 ];

    if( num < 0 ){
        num *= -1;
        isNeg = true;
    }

    // Fill buffer with digit characters in reverse order 
    while(num != 0){
        temp[i++] = (char)((num % 10) + ‘0’);
        num /= 10;
    }

    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    if( isNeg )
        b.append( ‘-’ );

    while( i > 0 ){
        b.append( temp[--i] );
    }

    return b.toString();
}
```

Could I get some help understanding the following lines of code:

```
    // Fill buffer with digit characters in reverse order 
    while(num != 0){
        temp[i++] = (char)((num % 10) + ‘0’);
        num /= 10;
    }
```

From what I understand, if num = 732, and i = 0:

```
temp [0] = "2"; //732 % 10 = 73.2 so 2 is the remainder?
num = 73.2; //732 divided by 10
temp [1] = "32"; //73.2 % 10 = 7.32 so 32 is the remainder?
num = 7.32; //73.2 divided by 10
temp [2] = "732"; //7.32 % 10 = 0.732 so 732 is the remainder?
num = 0.732; //7.32 divided by 10
```

num is now less than zero, so continue.

However, now we are walking backwards:

```
    while( i > 0 ){
        b.append( temp[--i] );
    }
```

But what I see from my physical calculations is:

```
String str = temp[2] + temp[1] + temp[0]; 
str = "732" + "32" + "2";
```

What is actually happening is temp is storing:

```
    temp[2] = 7; 
    temp[1] = 3;
    temp[0] = 2;
```

To get:

```
   str = "732";
```

But I don't understand how temp is getting just the one number.

Comment: Why are you thinking `str = temp[2] + temp[1] + temp[0]` is `str = "732" + "32" + "2"`? Each `temp[i]` is a character. Also, `n /= 10` is an integer divide, so if `n = 732`, then `n /= 10` yields `n = 73` and `n /= 10` again yields `n = 7`...

Comment: I see that: 
temp [0] = "2"; //num = 732 % 10 = 73.2 so 2 is the remainder and becomes the value of temp...
temp [1] = "32"; //73.2 % 10 = 7.32 so 32 is the remainder?
temp [2] = "732"; //7.32 % 10 = 0.732 so 732 is the remainder?

Comment: @Ubez You seem to be confusing `/` with `%` -- one is the modulo operator and the other is the division operator.

Comment: Each `temp[i]` is a character. Set as `(char)((num % 10) + '0')`. And `%` is modulo as @devnull indicated.

Comment: Oh DARN! You are right, num is an interger, so the double value is not being stored. I shouldn't be focusing on the decimal values... Duh. Thank you guys! I see my mistake now.

Comment: for such small arrays, static declaration is much better

Answer (score 0):

So lets run through your program.

```
// Fill buffer with digit characters in reverse order 
while(num != 0){
    temp[i++] = (char)((num % 10) + ‘0’);
    num /= 10;
}

When i is 0 and num is 732   
first case
temp[0] = (char)((732%10) +'0');
temp[0] now has the value of 2
next line 732/=10
num = 73
tem[1] = (char)((73%10 +'0');
temp [1] now has the value of 3  
next line 73/=10
temp[2] = (char)((7%10 +'0');
temp[2] now has the value of 7
```

Comment: This was the problem, I did the same thing you showed above but the code is actually:

    When i is 0 and num is 732    
    first case
    temp[0] = (char)((732%10) +'0');
    temp[0] now has the value of 2
    next line 732/=10
    num = 73
    tem[1] = (char)((73%10 +'0');
    temp [1] now has the value of 3  
    next line 73/=10
    temp[2] = (char)((7%10 +'0');
    temp[2] now has the value of 7

I had to ignore the double value, and just focus on the integer value I was storing. x[

Comment: How are you getting temp[2] = 732? num is an int you can't get decimals